# How to keep jquery drop down menu open when hovering off the li class

Tags: jquery, html, css

The menu ul class will stretch full width on top , when hovering the li class it triggers the drop content to open. I would like to keep the drop content of the last li hovered open, when your mouse is still in the "ul" , and only have the content hide when your mouse completely off the menu. jsFiddle set up, blue bg field is the "ul" class i'd like the last content to remain open when your mouse is still there.

http://jsfiddle.net/R7aTq/150/

```
(function($){

  $.fn.naviDropDown = function(options) {  

    //set up default options 
    var defaults = { 
        dropDownClass: 'dropdown', //the class name for your drop down
        dropDownWidth: 'auto',  //the default width of drop down elements
        slideDownEasing: 'easeInOutCirc', //easing method for slideDown
        slideUpEasing: 'easeInOutCirc', //easing method for slideUp
        slideDownDuration: 500, //easing duration for slideDown
        slideUpDuration: 500, //easing duration for slideUp
        orientation: 'horizontal' //orientation - either 'horizontal' or 'vertical'
    }; 

    var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);     

    return this.each(function() {  
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).css('width', opts.dropDownWidth).css('display', 'none');

      var buttonWidth = $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).parent().width() + 'px';
      var buttonHeight = $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).parent().height() + 'px';
      if(opts.orientation == 'horizontal') {
        $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).css('left', '0px').css('top', buttonHeight);
      }
      if(opts.orientation == 'vertical') {
        $this.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).css('left', buttonWidth).css('top', '0px');
      }

      $this.find('li').hoverIntent(getDropDown, hideDropDown);
    });

    function getDropDown(){
        activeNav = $(this);
        showDropDown();
    }

    function showDropDown(){
        activeNav.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).slideDown({duration:opts.slideDownDuration, easing:opts.slideDownEasing});
    }

    function hideDropDown(){
        activeNav.find('.'+opts.dropDownClass).slideUp({duration:opts.slideUpDuration, easing:opts.slideUpEasing});//hides the current dropdown
    }

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: can be done but is not trivial and not likely to happen in a help forum for such localized situation. Have to remove `hoverintent` and rewrite individual mouse events and timers and make it cross browser compatible. Suggest hring someone

Answer (score 0):

Try having a separate `hoverIntent()` check on the `ul` as well. This way you'll be able to control the activation of the dropdown on the `li` and the deactivation on the `ul`. You'll need to have a properly scoped variable to keep track of the active navigation item.

Here's an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R7aTq/170/

I moved the plugin code into the JS section. You can see that I added another `hoverIntent()` call and updated the dropdown functions to handle closing an existing dropdown if a new one is being opened. See if that works for you.

Comment: Jon, that is working perfectly for me. The only question I have is, is it possible when you open the initial li drop content, whichever one that may be, and then you hover the next li , that the content doesn't retract, rather the content box adjust itself to the new content of the li opened ? I was planning on having the drop content go full width, and the up and down accordian of the dropcontent is annoying as heck. So if you have one open, and hover another li, instead of closing the old, and opening the new, simply have the new content populated ?  Thanks for the help